# Invalid write to global property QML

Tags: qt, properties, qt4, qml, qtdeclarative

I have this signal

```
class SystemUICfgScanner 
{
    /*code here*/
signals:
    void error(QString desc);
    /*more code*/
};
```

In QML I use an InfoBanner this way:

```
InfoBanner
{
    property string infodetails: ""
    id: systemuicfgErrorBanner
    text: "Error: " + infodetails
    Connections
    {
        target: cfgScanner
        onError: infodetails = desc
    }
}
```

When error(QString) signal is emitted, I'm getting this error

```
Invalid write to global property "infodetails"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use `onError: systemuicfgErrorBanner.infodetails = desc`

Comment: @aleks_misyuk, sorry for duplicating, I noticed your comment only after posting an answer..

Comment: Can somebody explain the cause of this error ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to reference `InfoBanner` instance by id:

```
InfoBanner
{
    property string infodetails: ""
    id: systemuicfgErrorBanner
    text: "Error: " + infodetails
    Connections
    {
        target: cfgScanner
        onError: systemuicfgErrorBanner.infodetails = desc
    }
}
```